# Longtable goes wrong after page break

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I am really new to LaTeX and I am using the following codes to make a long table cross pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}


\caption{A table} \\\hline

\backslashbox[-1cm][0]{$c$}{$N_1$}& 0.01    & 0.02    & 0.03    & 0.04    & 0.05    & 0.06    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.07}    \\ \hline

$c_1$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_2$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_3$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_4$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_5$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_6$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_7$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_8$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_9$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0011}  \\ \hline

$c_{10}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0016}  \\ \hline

$c_{11}$ & 0.0033  & 0.0025  & 0.0019  & 0.0013  & 0.0008  & 0.0003  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0005}  \\ \hline

$c_{12}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0006}  \\ \hline

$c_{13}$& 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_{14}$ & 0.0095  & 0.0071  & 0.0053  & 0.0038  & 0.0023  & 0.0008  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_{15}$ & -0.0004 & -0.0092 & -0.0114 & -0.0147 & -0.0179 & -0.0211 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0234} \\ \hline

$c_{16}$& 0.0001  & -0.0036 & -0.0065 & -0.0090 & -0.0114 & -0.0139 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0155} \\ \hline

$c_{17}$ & 0.0000  & -0.0014 & -0.0035 & -0.0081 & -0.0127 & -0.0174 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0206} \\ \hline

$c_{18}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & -0.0016 & -0.0075 & -0.0133 & -0.0192 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0232} \\ \hline

$c_{19}$ & 0.0000  & -0.0001 & -0.0051 & -0.0051 & -0.0051 & -0.0051 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0052} \\ \hline

$c_{20}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

\backslashbox[-1cm][0]{$c$}{$N_1$}& 0.08    & 0.09    & 0.1     & 0.11    & 0.12    & 0.13    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.14}    \\ \hline

$c_1$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_2$& 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_3$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_4$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

$c_5$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \\ \hline

 \backslashbox[-1cm][0]{$c$}{$N_1$}& 0.15    & 0.16    & 0.17    & 0.18    & 0.19    & 0.2     &                               \\ \cline{1-7}
$c_1$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_2$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_3$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_4$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_5$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_6$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_7$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7} 

$c_8$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_9$  & 0.0077  & 0.0075  & 0.0073  & 0.0072  & 0.0070  & 0.0068  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_{10}$ & 0.0046  & 0.0047  & 0.0047  & 0.0047  & 0.0048  & 0.0048  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_{11}$ & -0.0003 & -0.0007 & -0.0011 & -0.0015 & -0.0019 & -0.0023 &                              \\\cline{1-7}

$c_{12}$& 0.0019  & 0.0016  & 0.0013  & 0.0009  & 0.0006  & 0.0003  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_{13}$& 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \\ \cline{1-7}

$c_{14}$& -0.0070 & -0.0080 & -0.0091 & -0.0102 & -0.0113 & -0.0124 &                              \\ \cline{1-7}



\end{longtable}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

However for the first row on the second page, the upper horizontal border is missing and it seems to only stay at the previous page like this:[image]
[image]

I am guessing it is because I use `\cline` for some of the rows but I don't know how to fix it. 
Thanks in advance for you help :).

Comment: `slashbox` is a really old package.

Comment: Apart from my answer: I suggest to split this huge table in two separate longtables, one with 8 columns and the other one with 7 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the commands `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` from `longtable` package to solve this issue (however, this is not failsafe)

As it stands, the number of table columns is reduced by one in the lower part of the first page and for the rest which should appear on the second page, so `\cline{1-7}` is the correct form for horizontal lines there.

```
\endfirsthead

\cline{1-7}
\endhead
```

will first provide the  `\hline` for the first head (i.e. the table header on the first page.) and afterwards it's changed to `\cline{1-7}` for **any** following header on the remaining page(s).

This procedure requires finetuning!

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|*{7}{c|}c} % Shorter form (easier to handle)
%\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}

\endfirsthead

\cline{1-7}
\endhead
\caption{A table} \tabularnewline\hline

\backslashbox[-1cm][0]{$c$}{$N_1$}& 0.01    & 0.02    & 0.03    & 0.04    & 0.05    & 0.06    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.07}    \tabularnewline \hline

$c_1$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_2$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_3$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_4$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_5$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_6$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_7$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_8$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_9$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0011}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{10}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0016}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{11}$ & 0.0033  & 0.0025  & 0.0019  & 0.0013  & 0.0008  & 0.0003  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0005}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{12}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0006}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{13}$& 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{14}$ & 0.0095  & 0.0071  & 0.0053  & 0.0038  & 0.0023  & 0.0008  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{15}$ & -0.0004 & -0.0092 & -0.0114 & -0.0147 & -0.0179 & -0.0211 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0234} \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{16}$& 0.0001  & -0.0036 & -0.0065 & -0.0090 & -0.0114 & -0.0139 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0155} \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{17}$ & 0.0000  & -0.0014 & -0.0035 & -0.0081 & -0.0127 & -0.0174 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0206} \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{18}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & -0.0016 & -0.0075 & -0.0133 & -0.0192 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0232} \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{19}$ & 0.0000  & -0.0001 & -0.0051 & -0.0051 & -0.0051 & -0.0051 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{-0.0052} \tabularnewline \hline

$c_{20}$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

\backslashbox[-1cm][0]{$c$}{$N_1$}& 0.08    & 0.09    & 0.1     & 0.11    & 0.12    & 0.13    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.14}    \tabularnewline \hline

$c_1$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_2$& 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_3$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_4$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

$c_5$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0.0000}  \tabularnewline \hline

 \backslashbox[-1cm][0]{$c$}{$N_1$}& 0.15    & 0.16    & 0.17    & 0.18    & 0.19    & 0.2     &                               \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}
$c_1$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_2$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_3$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_4$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_5$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_6$ & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_7$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7} 

$c_8$  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_9$  & 0.0077  & 0.0075  & 0.0073  & 0.0072  & 0.0070  & 0.0068  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_{10}$ & 0.0046  & 0.0047  & 0.0047  & 0.0047  & 0.0048  & 0.0048  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_{11}$ & -0.0003 & -0.0007 & -0.0011 & -0.0015 & -0.0019 & -0.0023 &                              \tabularnewline\cline{1-7}

$c_{12}$& 0.0019  & 0.0016  & 0.0013  & 0.0009  & 0.0006  & 0.0003  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_{13}$& 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  & 0.0000  &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}

$c_{14}$& -0.0070 & -0.0080 & -0.0091 & -0.0102 & -0.0113 & -0.0124 &                              \tabularnewline \cline{1-7}



\end{longtable}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No comments on the various lines in this table please ;-) That's another issue ;-)

Comment: @JennyLiang: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!